# Member Group Tabs throws blank screen after EE upgrade to 2.10

Tags: ee2, extension

After an update to EE 2.10.1 the module Member Group Tabs throws the following error:

Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in /path/sh_member_group_tabs/ext.sh_member_group_tabs.php on line 277.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance, 
Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

open file */system/expressionengine/third_party/ext.sh_member_group_tabs.php* 
and change line 270:

```
if (APP_VER >= '2.6.0')
```

to

```
if (version_compare(APP_VER, '2.6.0', '>='))
```

it is also needs to make search & replace for  **APP_VER >= '2.6.0'** & **APP_VER >= '2.8'** and replace it with  **version_compare(APP_VER, '2.6.0', '>=')** & **version_compare(APP_VER, '2.8', '>=')**

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Rakesh and Tom. Member Group Tabs is now compatible with EE v2.10.1.